# Function returning the return of another function

Tags: c++, function, vector, return-value

If I want to call `Bar()` instead of `Foo()`, does `Bar()` return me a copy (additional overhead) of what Foo() returns, or it returns the same object which `Foo()` places on the temporary stack?

```
vector<int> Foo(){  
    vector<int> result;  
    result.push_back(1);  
    return result;  
}  
vector<int> Bar(){  
    return Foo();  
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both may happen. However, most compiler will not do copy as soon as you optimize.

Your code indicate there should be a copy. However, the compiler is allowed to remove any copy that do not change the semantic and the program.

Note: This is why you should NEVER have a copy constructor that does anything but copying correctly as you can never be sure if a copy will be actually done or not.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a place the compiler is allowed to remove the copy from (inlining would remove it though). So yes a the vector is copied from Foo() to Bar() then copied from Bar() to the caller. A lot of work has been done to make copying std::vector<> very efficient. So dont worry.

Comment: I think the compiler can optimize this safely as a single copy using Return Value Optimization (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(VS.80).aspx).

Basically if the variable would be constructed and immediately copies, it can just construct direct to where it would be copied.

Comment: This is absolutely a place where the optimization takes place, even without inlining.

Comment: Will it be optimised as well if the two functions are in different classes? Actually this is the actual thing I wanted to ask but neglected to mention the conditions properly.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it returns a copy of the returned `vector<int>`. However this highly depends on the optimization done by the compiler. See the following discussion.

**Debug Build**

```
vector<int> Foo(){  
004118D0  push        ebp  
004118D1  mov         ebp,esp 
004118D3  push        0FFFFFFFFh 
004118D5  push        offset __ehhandler$?Foo@@YA?AV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@XZ (419207h) 
004118DA  mov         eax,dword ptr fs:[00000000h] 
004118E0  push        eax  
004118E1  sub         esp,0F4h 
004118E7  push        ebx  
004118E8  push        esi  
004118E9  push        edi  
004118EA  lea         edi,[ebp-100h] 
004118F0  mov         ecx,3Dh 
004118F5  mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh 
004118FA  rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 
004118FC  mov         eax,dword ptr [___security_cookie (41E098h)] 
00411901  xor         eax,ebp 
00411903  push        eax  
00411904  lea         eax,[ebp-0Ch] 
00411907  mov         dword ptr fs:[00000000h],eax 
0041190D  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0F0h],0 
    vector<int> result;  
00411917  lea         ecx,[ebp-24h] 
0041191A  call        std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::vector<int,std::allocator<int> > (411050h) 
0041191F  mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],1 
    result.push_back(1);  
00411926  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0FCh],1 
00411930  lea         eax,[ebp-0FCh] 
00411936  push        eax  
00411937  lea         ecx,[ebp-24h] 
0041193A  call        std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::push_back (41144Ch) 
    return result;  
0041193F  lea         eax,[ebp-24h] 
00411942  push        eax  
00411943  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+8] 
00411946  call        std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::vector<int,std::allocator<int> > (41104Bh) 
0041194B  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-0F0h] 
00411951  or          ecx,1 
00411954  mov         dword ptr [ebp-0F0h],ecx 
0041195A  mov         byte ptr [ebp-4],0 
0041195E  lea         ecx,[ebp-24h] 
00411961  call        std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::~vector<int,std::allocator<int> > (411415h) 
00411966  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp+8] 
}
```

Here we can see that for `vector<int> result;` a new object is created on the stack at `[ebp-24h]`

```
00411917  lea         ecx,[ebp-24h] 
0041191A  call        std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::vector<int,std::allocator<int> > (411050h)
```

When we get to `return result;` a new copy is created in storage allocated by the caller at `[ebp+8]`

```
00411943  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp+8] 
00411946  call        std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::vector<int,std::allocator<int> > (41104Bh)
```

And the destructor is called for the local parameter `vector<int> result` at `[ebp-24h]`

```
0041195E  lea         ecx,[ebp-24h] 
00411961  call        std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::~vector<int,std::allocator<int> > (411415h)
```

**Release Build**

```
vector<int> Foo(){  
00401110  push        0FFFFFFFFh 
00401112  push        offset __ehhandler$?Foo@@YA?AV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@XZ (401F89h) 
00401117  mov         eax,dword ptr fs:[00000000h] 
0040111D  push        eax  
0040111E  sub         esp,14h 
00401121  push        esi  
00401122  mov         eax,dword ptr [___security_cookie (403018h)] 
00401127  xor         eax,esp 
00401129  push        eax  
0040112A  lea         eax,[esp+1Ch] 
0040112E  mov         dword ptr fs:[00000000h],eax 
00401134  mov         esi,dword ptr [esp+2Ch] 
00401138  xor         eax,eax 
0040113A  mov         dword ptr [esp+8],eax 
    vector<int> result;  
0040113E  mov         dword ptr [esi+4],eax 
00401141  mov         dword ptr [esi+8],eax 
00401144  mov         dword ptr [esi+0Ch],eax 
    result.push_back(1);  
    return result;  
00401147  push        eax  
00401148  mov         dword ptr [esp+28h],eax 
0040114C  mov         ecx,1 
00401151  push        esi  
00401152  lea         eax,[esp+14h] 
00401156  mov         dword ptr [esp+10h],ecx 
0040115A  mov         dword ptr [esp+14h],ecx 
0040115E  push        eax  
0040115F  lea         ecx,[esp+1Ch] 
00401163  push        ecx  
00401164  mov         eax,esi 
00401166  call        std::vector<int,std::allocator<int> >::insert (401200h) 
0040116B  mov         eax,esi 
}  
0040116D  mov         ecx,dword ptr [esp+1Ch] 
00401171  mov         dword ptr fs:[0],ecx 
00401178  pop         ecx  
00401179  pop         esi  
0040117A  add         esp,20h 
0040117D  ret
```

The line `vector<int> result` does not call the vector allocator because it is done at call site in `Bar`. The optimization makes no copy of the result from Foo.

Comment: I do think this explication is a bit overkill ...
And highly depend on the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

This is a trivial case for NRVO – names return value optimization (a misnomer in this case since there's no name). Stan Lippman hat a [blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/slippman/archive/2004/02/03/66739.aspx) with a nice explanation of the mechanism involved.

Comment: Isn't it just called RVO when the temporary wasn't named.

Comment: @David: Yes, by some, and I used to call it that myself. However, there seem to be no mentions of “RVO” in technical literature. “NRVO” is used as the technical term encompassing this.