# Returning the value of a function with multiple input parameters to use in another function with multiple parameters inside the same Class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Now I know there are many duplicates asking a similar question [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166113/function-returning-the-return-of-another-function)[[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318941/how-to-use-the-return-value-of-a-function-with-parameters-inside-another-functio)[[3]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26221148/return-function-that-modifies-the-value-of-the-input-function)[[4]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20125222/class-return-value-to-another-function-in-same-class)[[5]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35831809/passing-function-values-to-another-function-in-same-class), however I believe none of them call a function with multiple input parameters inside another function with multiple parameters in the same Class; which happens to be my particular problem (unless I missed it during my search).

Below is a minimum working example where I am trying to use the results of function1 in function2:

```
class Something():
    def __init__(self,input1, input2, input3):
        self.input1 = input1
        self.input2 = input2
        self.input3 = input3

    def function1(self, input4, input5, input6):
        something = (self.input1 +  self.input2 + self.input3)+input4+input5+input6
        return something

    def function2(self, input7, input8):
        something2 = self.function1(self.input4, self.input5, self.input6)+input7+input8
        return something2        

a = Something(1,2,3)
print(a.function1(4,5,6))
print(a.function2(7, 8))
```

Function1 prints out fine, however when I call Function2, I get an error:

```
AttributeError: 'Something' object has no attribute 'input4'
```

I'm probably missing a simple step here, however I can't seem to figure out how to use the results of function1 inside function2 without having to redefining all the input parameters again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input4` is an argument whose scope is local to `function1`. The same applies to `input5` and `input6`. You need to assign them using `self` in the `__init__` in order to make them accessible to the class methods using the `self` instance. If you want these variables to be accessible without redefining them in the argument list, you can assign them using `self` in the `function1`

```
class Something():
    def __init__(self,input1, input2, input3):
        self.input1 = input1
        self.input2 = input2
        self.input3 = input3

    def function1(self, input4, input5, input6):
        self.input4 = input4
        self.input5 = input5
        self.input6 = input6
        something = (self.input1 +  self.input2 + self.input3)+input4+input5+input6
        return something

    def function2(self, input7, input8):
        something2 = self.function1(self.input4, self.input5, self.input6)+input7+input8
        return something2        

a = Something(1,2,3)
print(a.function1(4,5,6))
print(a.function2(7, 8))

# 21 
# 36
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.input4` makes no sense, because it's not a field that you give to `self` in `__init__`.

If you want to use `self.input4` in `function2`, then either `__init__` or `function1` need to assign `self.input4 = # something`.

Answer (score 0):

Just by adding another argument to `function2`, you can either pass the results of `function1` to `function2`, or just call `function1` in the args of `function2`.

```
class Something():
    def __init__(self,input1, input2, input3):
        self.input1 = input1
        self.input2 = input2
        self.input3 = input3

    def function1(self, input4, input5, input6):
        something = (self.input1 +  self.input2 + self.input3)+input4+input5+input6
        return something

    def function2(self, input7, input8, res1):
        something2 = res1+input7+input8
        return something2

a = Something(1,2,3)

# just save the result of function1 and pass it to function2
res1 = a.function1(4,5,6)
print(res1)
print(a.function2(7, 8, res1))

# or just call function1 in the arg list of function2
print(a.function2(7, 8, a.function1(4,5,6)))
```

Answer (score 0):

"Scope" is a fancy term to denote the accessibility, and often lifetime of variables. `input4` cannot be seen inside `function2` because it's only defined by the name `input4` within `function1`.  If you want to use it in another function, you should pass it as a parameter or save it as state.

Your second function doesn't actually depend directly on the internal state of your object, so you can just split it out as a function separate from your class.  `function1` should have a meaning and pass that meaning into your other function.

```
# A separately reusable function, not dependent on Something
def function2(foo, input7, input8):
    something2 = foo + input7 + input8
    return something2        

class Something():
    def __init__(self,input1, input2, input3):
        self.input1 = input1
        self.input2 = input2
        self.input3 = input3

    def function1(self, input4, input5, input6):
        something = (self.input1 +  self.input2 + self.input3)+input4+input5+input6
        return something

a = Something(1,2,3)
print(a.function1(4,5,6))
print(function2(a.function1(4,5,6), 8))
```